# How do dry bays protect against fire?

Tags: aircraft-design, fire

How do [dry bays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_bay) protect against fire, and do civil aircraft also have dry bays like military aircraft?

Comment: The article you linked to doesn't state that dry bays protect against fire. Quite the opposite: it states that dry bays are fire *hazards*, which is precisely why they *need* to be kept dry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, civil also aircraft have “Dry Bays” but they do not protect against fire. A dry bay is an area adjacent to a fuel tank that holds various components.

Some aircraft (mostly military?) have fire extinguishers or fire suppression equipment in dry bays but this will vary considerably with each type. (the B777 has no fire suppression in the dry bays)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer to include info from your link.